# Custom building SGEN assemblies and including in installer

Tags: visual-studio, sgen

I've been rather confused by some SGEN stuff. I've enable the generation of serialization assemblies for one of my projects. Originally I got the follow error which I believe I've solved by doing some caspol stuff on a remote assembly.

> Unable to load one or more of the request types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions propery for more information

Now however, I don't get an assembly generated. Adding some debugging/verbose output provides the message "SS.dll does not contain any types that can be serialized using XmlSerializer". I've read that this is because of a proxy switch applied by VS. The odd thing is it doesn't seem to be a problem with any other project.

So if I disable the proxy switch ([example here](http://blog.devstone.com/aaron/2008/02/07/UsingSGENexeFromWithinVisualStudio.aspx)) it seems to work. The linked build events however seem to do all projects. I don't know enough about MSBuild to tweak to just a single project, does anyone know what I need to change?

Additionally, if this change is made, is there a way I can automatically include this in a installer (VDProj)? I can't statically link to the SS.XmlSerializers.dll because the each dev uses a custom path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the following [post](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q100818.aspx) which talks about adding the `<SGenUseProxyTypes>Off</SGenUseProxyTypes>` to the csproj file which seems to work :)